# How to display multiple Cell Values on a Webpage in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am looking for a solution on how to display multiple cell values on a webpage. I know how to display single cell value (script below) on a website. What I need to display multiple cell values on a single webpage perhaps someone could help me out and check the code below.

```
<html>
  <head>
       <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
   

   <script type="text/javascript">

// https://google,developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets#gid
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
// Add your sheets url and range below
var spreadsheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u_5zfghxzxNHndfgJXJ73F6-NVS6tywcrS0/gviz/tq?tq=select%20A&tqx=out:csv";
var query = new google.visualization.Query(spreadsheetUrl);
query.send(handleQueryResponse);

function handleQueryResponse(response) {
var dataTable = response.getDataTable();
// https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en#methods
// getValue(rowIndex, columnIndex)
//document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = dataTable.getValue(0, 0);
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = (dataTable.getValue(0, 0)).toLocaleString();
}
      
    </script>

        

  </head>

  <body>
      <h2 class=""><span id="test"></span></h2>
           
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [quickstart from the Official documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visualization:Table to display your DataTable

[Visualization: Table](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table)

- A table that can be sorted and paged. Table cells can be formatted using format strings, or by directly inserting HTML as cell values. Numeric values are right-aligned; boolean values are displayed as check marks. Users can select single rows either with the keyboard or the mouse. Users can sort rows by clicking on column headers. The header row remains fixed as the user scrolls. The table fires a number of events corresponding to user interaction.

Sample:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
        data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
        ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="table_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

---

```
 var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));;
```

- creates a visualization table to a container named 'table_div'

---

```
table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
```

- draws the table with optional parameters

---

Your Code:

```
function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    var dataTable = response.getDataTable();
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('test'));
    table.draw(dataTable);
}
```

To learn more about the methods that you can use, please refer to this reference:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table#methods